# How to improve or optimize a particular Invoke-WebRequest in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, webrequest

I have this Powershell command:

```powershell
((Invoke-WebRequest https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/19344/intel-graphics-windows-10-windows-11-dch-drivers.html).AllElements | Where-Object -Property TagName -eq "META" | where -Property name -eq RecommendedDownloadUrl).content
```

I know that this can probably be done better, It's a specific question but I think I can learn a lot from your answers.
I want to just get the recommended URL from the META tag, to download the latest graphics driver from intel's website.

I ran one round of improvement, reducing `Where-Object` to just one command:

`((Invoke-WebRequest https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/19344/intel-graphics-windows-10-windows-11-dch-drivers.html).AllElements | Where-Object {$_.TagName -eq "META" -and $_.name -eq "RecommendedDownloadUrl"}).content`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can at least return only the elements that match the name you want with:

```
(Invoke-WebRequest https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/19344/intel-graphics-windows-10-windows-11-dch-drivers.html).ParsedHtml.getElementsByName('RecommendedDownloadUrl')
```

If you are ok with not specifying that it is META you can just take that result and get the content of it:

```
$((Invoke-WebRequest https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/19344/intel-graphics-windows-10-windows-11-dch-drivers.html).ParsedHtml.getElementsByName('RecommendedDownloadUrl')).content
```

Assuming that they only have one element named RecommendedDownloadUrl that should work fine. It still parses the page, so it probably isn't much faster, but it works with the object's inherent methods rather than pumping tons of objects through a `Where-Object` filter.

Comment: I ran both your version and my version with the "Measure-Command" cmdlet, and yours' 5 times faster (500ms vs 2500ms)

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't work on Powershell 7 hahaha

Answer (score 0):

This *is* probably the best way to do it - but if you want to optimize for speed, you could use the `-UseBasicParsing` switch to prevent PowerShell from spinning up a headless instance of Internet Explorer to parse the html (which is why it's slow):

```
$content = Invoke-WebRequest 'https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/19344/intel-graphics-windows-10-windows-11-dch-drivers.html' -UseBasicParsing |% Content
```

Now we have some raw html in a variable - now we just need to manually parse out the link in the relevant meta tag:

```
if($content -match '<meta\ name="RecommendedDownloadUrl"\ content="([^"]+)'){
  # grab link from capture group
  $Matches[1]
}
```

The reason I wouldn't consider this "better" than your current solution is that if intel makes changes to the HTML that wouldn't other affect the DOM, your script might break - if they suddenly switch the order of the attributes around it won't work anymore

Comment: Thank you Mathias, I did try your alternative method but I ran into several issues with regex, it does work but to a certain extent and as you said it has the issue of breaking if something changes.